# Как сделать вот такой прерывающийся border?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, border

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно сверстать такой border ?
Если бы фон был однотонный (белый, серый..)  - то я знаю как решить данную задачу. Но как е] решить, в случае если фон - это какая либо картинка ?
Помогите пожалуйста советом.

Comment: Простого способа нет. Обычно рамка делается в svg. В вашем случае нужна пара картинок, и вставляется либо фоном, либо с помощью before/after.

Answer (score -1):

4 div элемента с абсолютным позиционированием

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Nunito;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: auto;
}

.image {
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/949587/pexels-photo-949587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260");
}

h1 span {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 50%;
}
.title-box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 51px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #ffffff;
}


.title-border {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 71px;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}

.title-border-top-left {
    border-right: none;
}

.title-border-top-right {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    border-left: none;
    
}

.title-border-bottom-left {
    width: 100px;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.title-border-bottom-right {
    width: 100px;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="image">
    <h1>Международная онлайн школа</h1>
        <div class="title-box">
      
            <h1><span>Програмирования</span></h1>
            <ul class="list">
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
      <button class="button">Registration</button>
            <div class="title-border title-border-top-left"></div>
      <div class="title-border title-border-bottom-left"></div>
            <div class="title-border title-border-top-right"></div>
      <div class="title-border title-border-bottom-right"></div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: это в случае с однотипным фоном. так я тоже могу. мне нужно именно что бы на фоне картинки. дабы этому тексту я не мог задать бэкграунд (

Comment: Вот так пойдет ?
https://js-qrhth2.stackblitz.io

Comment: оО
похоже это то, что нужно!
каааааак ?))

Comment: поправил ответ выше

Comment: СПАСИБО!
Поиграюсь с адаптивом, надеюсь получится)
а то уже второй день не могу понять как это лучше сделать.

Comment: не факт что лучший вариант но есть от чего оттолкнутся

Comment: другого варианта у меня пока нет, так что на данный момент это лучший!